# jquery Current Nav item selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation, nav

I can't figure out how to use jQuery to style the current nav item. I've tried several tutorials and such to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
    <div id="menu">
     <ul id="nav">  
      <li><a href="http://poolguys.jaredmc.com/index.php">Contact</a></li> 
      <li><a href="http://poolguys.jaredmc.com/index.php">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://poolguys.jaredmc.com/pool_liners.php">Pool Liners</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://poolguys.jaredmc.com/services.php">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://poolguys.jaredmc.com/about.php">About</a></li> 
      <li><a href="http://poolguys.jaredmc.com/index.php">Home</a></li> 
    </ul><!--end nav-->         
  </div><!--end menu--> 

   /** nav styling **/

   //<![CDATA[
    jQuery(function() {
     jQuery('#nav li').each(function() {
      var href = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');
      if (href === window.location.pathname) {
      jQuery(this).addClass('current');
       }
      });
    });  
  //]]>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do this on the server side?

Comment: Hey Dennis- can you be more specific? Thanks

Comment: Instead of adding the class on the client side, echo `class="current"` in PHP for the link that matches the requested URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to find out the nav item with the current path.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var str = location.href.toLowerCase();
    var item  = $('#nav li a[href="' + str  + '"]');
    if(item.length){
        $("li.current").removeClass("current");
        item.parent().addClass("current");
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g6cD6/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! However when I pasted the above code into the custom.js file it doesn't work.When I remove your // hard coded string the operation fails.

Comment: no luck- my custom.js : $(document).ready(function () {
    var str = location.href.toLowerCase();
    $("#nav li a").each(function () {
        if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            $("li.current").removeClass("current");
            $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        }
    });

/**HOME PAGE Callout Boxes**/
$("div.individual_callout a").hover(function()
{
    $("div.individual_callout a").stop().animate({opacity:0.4},400);
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1},1);
},
function(){
    $("div.individual_callout a").stop().animate({opacity:4},400);
    });

});

Comment: try to alert `alert(str)` to see the path value

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!! Thanks for your help Will.i.am and Arun.p.
THe lines of code below is all I needed after giving body id's to each page.

```
     /** nav selector **/
     var bodyid = $('body').attr('id');  
     $('#main_nav ul li a.'+ bodyid).addClass('current');
```